# Initialise a NoUiSlider [min,max] range values from the KO binding

Tags: knockout.js, binding, nouislider

My code is similar to the KO part of the example in [this fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/shxcmpc8/4/).

I need to add a dynamic initialization of the range *values* [min, max] of the slider, and so I replace line 32 of the javascript

`ko.applyBindings(new model());`

by

```
var r = new model();
ko.applyBindings(r);
r.min(2222);
r.max(3333);`
```

The 2 input texts are updated but the slider is not.

Why not? ... and how to get the slider to display the initialized range?

Comment: two-way bindings of a widget means, that you need also the update function in your bindinghandler, where you put the dependency from your viewmodel and set the value of your slider

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that whenever `min` or `max` are updated through code (instead of via the UI), the slider's `updateOptions` is called.

This can be done by manually subscribing to `model.min` and `model.max`, or by putting the logic inside a `ko.computed`. The dependency has to be created inside the custom binding's `init` method. This function is executed *once* upon binding the element.

```
ko.computed(function() {
  element.noUiSlider.updateOptions({
    range: {
      'min': model.min(),
      'max': model.max()
    }
  });
});
```

Make sure you attach the right disposal logic if you plan to remove and re-add these elements from/to the DOM frequently.